# How to determine link with in a another web element is clickable

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on a project. I have to determine that whether a link is clickable or not. Here is the link:

```
<div id="divMegamenu" class="column span_10_of_16 center_text mega_menu">
<a href="#" class="close_popup menu"></a>
    <nav class="desktop_mega">
        <ul>
            <li id="g_women">
                <span class="global_cat"><a href="http://www.forever21.com/Product/Category.aspx?br=f21&amp;category=app-main">women</a></span>
```

Following is the xpath that I have written:

```
 WebElement imgElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id = 'desktop_mega']/ul/li[@id='g_women']/span[@id='global_cat']/a"));
```

But it keeps on raising the exception that no such element

Answer (score 0):

`desktop_mega` and `global_cat` are classes, not ids. Replace `nav[@id = 'desktop_mega']` with `nav[@class='desktop_mega']` and `span[@id='global_cat']` with `span[@class='global_cat']`

```
WebElement imgElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@class='desktop_mega']/ul/li[@id='g_women']/span[@class='global_cat']/a"));
```

Comment: I just found out problem is not with xpath but it is with imgElement.click()

Comment: @puffles what is `imgElement.click()`?

Comment: imgElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@class='desktop_mega']/ul/li[@id='g_women']/span[@class='global_cat']/a"));